# SF & Windows Server 2016

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Now that Windows Server 2016 Datacenter is available as an option in Azure I'd love to utilize it for new SF clusters. Is this something that is supported today by SF? If it's not specifically supported does anyone know what types of issues I might run into? Surely plenty of people have tried during the betas/previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since nobody wants to tackle this I'll provide my own answer. It appears the Service Fabric can and does support Windows Server 2016 Datacenter as the OS for nodes. I've tweaked my ARM template to look like this:

```
        "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
            "version": "latest"
        }
```

And all seems to deploy and function correctly, so far.

Comment: I know I'm kind of digging up an old topic but do you know if it is possible to upgrade the VMs from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2016?